# Flutter: Conditional switches and adding/removing from a list

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a switch that will either add or remove a value from a list.

I've created my stateful widget and a boolean variable for my switch:

```dart
class CustomisePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _CustomisePageState();
  }
}

class _CustomisePageState extends State<CustomisePage> {
  List<String> names = ["Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3", "Name 4"];
  bool isSwitched = true;
```

I've created my switch with a conditional statement checks whether the switch is turned "on", and the list doesn't contain the value "Name 1", then adds the value to the list `names`. If the switch is turned "off", it removes "Name 1" from the list.

```dart
SwitchListTile(
  activeColor: Colors.amber,
  value: isSwitched,
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      isSwitched = value;
      if (isSwitched = true && names.contains("Name 1") = false) {
        names.add("Name 1");
      } else {
        names.remove("Name 1");
      }
    });
  },
  title: Text("Name 1"),
  secondary: const Icon(Icons.add),
)
```

This issue however is that Flutter/Dart doesn't like "games.contains("Name 1") = false" statement I've created to check if the value is in the list.

I would really appreciate any help, or even advice on improving my code to make it more efficient!

Comment: Heya thank you for making the edits!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `isSwitched == true && names.contains("Name 1") == false` or better `isSwitched && !names.contains("Name 1")`

Using a single `=` is an assignment which cannot be done here

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before using single = is for assigning a value, it is not comparable operator if you want to check equality you must use this == operator.